# displaying a list of entities in jsp file by using java

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I am trying to display list of entities in a .jsp file, but I this error:

```
Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 28 in the jsp file: /guestbook.jsp
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
25:     </tr>
26:     <tr>
27:     <%
28:         for (Entity drugtarget : "${drugtargets}") {
29:         %>
30:     <td> 
31:     <%
```

Here is my query from servlet class:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query query = new Query("DrugTarget").addSort("drug", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
List<Entity> drugtargets = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));

req.setAttribute("drugtargets", drugtargets);
```

And this is how I send drugtargets to jsp file:

```
String url = "/guestbook.jsp";
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher(url);
try {
    rd.forward(req, resp);
} catch (ServletException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Finally here is how I write jsp part:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Drug Names</th>
    <th>Target Names</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <%
      for (Entity drugtarget : "${drugtargets}") {
    %>
    <td> 
    <%
      pageContext.setAttribute("drug_content",
                                drugtarget.getProperty("drug"));
    %>
    ${fn:escapeXml(drug_content)}
    </td>
    <td>
    <%
      pageContext.setAttribute("target_content",
                                drugtarget.getProperty("target"));
    %>
    ${fn:escapeXml(target_content)}
    </td>   
    <%
      }
    %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think I'm making a syntax mistake, but I'm not sure. I checked some examples and the same way (to send list of entities from servlet to jsp and to reach entities in jsp file) was used. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using *scriptlets* (those oldschool `<% %>` things with Java code) at all when using servlets and EL. Use taglibs like [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) instead. It offers the [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag to iterate over a collection.

For example,

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Drug Names</th>
    <th>Target Names</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${drugtargets}" var="drugtarget">
    <tr>
      <td>${fn:escapeXml(drugtarget.drug)}</td>
      <td>${fn:escapeXml(drugtarget.target)}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

*(note that I also fixed the rendering of table rows by putting the `<tr>` inside the loop)*

Much simpler, isn't it? You can by the way also just use `<c:out value="${drugtarget.drug}"/>` instead of those functions.

If you can, I suggest to add the following to your webapp's `web.xml` in order to disable *scriptlets* altogether so that you will be forced to do things the right way.

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

Comment: should I delete this line <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

Comment: No, definitely not. It just declares the taglib. It doesn't embed some Java code.

Answer (score 1):

In this case "${drugtargets}" is a String, not the list you passed.  I would recommend using the  looping. It's way cleaner.

```
<c:forEach var="drugtarget " items="${drugtargets}"> 
.... Your code here ...
</c:forEach>
```